# How can I add a web link to the user's home screen using a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

In the old TestFlight, before Apple took it over and produced a native app, you would enrol a device by loading Safari, logging in, and downloading a provisioning profile (or something similar). You would be prompted to approve the profile, which would add an icon to your home screen.

Tapping this icon would load Safari, but there would no chrome, and the website behind was designed to look like a native iOS application.

I am investigating whether I could use this would like to use this technique to simplify the distribution of a web application link which would appear to be an app.

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on how this is done. It is likely I do not know the correct name for this technique. Or perhaps, is this feature now no longer available?

I am aware that it's possible for a user to do this themselves but I'd like to simplify the process if possible - it is likely that these users will already not be comfortable with iOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: It pertains to web applications, and provisioning profiles which definitely count as programming. I think it would be at least helpful to have the above terms indexed so someone else can get this information in the future. If you couldn't sign your IPA with a provisioning profile, would that not be programming?

Comment: In the Apple development world there are different roles for development, distribution and other stuff.  Your question is about distribution.

Comment: Where would you recommend asking this question? I don't believe the Apple stackexchange site would be suitable for example. I certainly don't think the question should be closed but perhaps it should be moved. Please note also that stack overflow is about questions relevant to programers. Programmers don't just write code, they are often responsible for making sure people can get the product as well.

Comment: I would imagine the Apple Developer Forums are the most appropriate place.  Programmers only write code; perhaps someone might design, program and promote an app all on her own, however she is only a programmer during the second bit.

Comment: Yes, but they're not indexed by seach engines are they? That's not very helpful for future developers. I see where you're coming from here but I think we'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In good news, this turns out to be quite easy to do. The object behaves like a provisioning profile, and even has a similar-looking icon but it is actually called a configuration profile.

Configuration Profiles can be created using Apple Configurator, which is available on the Mac App Store. Simply load Apple Configurator, create a new profile (Cmd-N) and select to create a new Web Clip. Save the profile and distribute it to users.